# Longtable alternative for twocolumn documents?

Tags: page-breaking, two-column, longtable

Is there a recommended method for incorporating multi-page tables into `twocolumn` documents?  It's clear that the `longtable` package isn't set up to deal with documents of more than one column.

Is there an alternative package that will deal better with the `twocolumn` format?

Alternatively, what's the best way of putting `longtable` (or equivalent) into a `twocolumn` document as a single column float?  Is there something similar to `table*` and `figure*`, but for `longtable`?

Comment: Thanks!  I've gotten supertabular to generate tables now, but have not yet figured out how force it to be single-column (similar to figure*), which I am now realizing is really necessary given my table width.

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand.  Will tabularx handle page breaks?

Answer (score 5):

How float environments are handled in LaTeX can you read in the answer of Frank Mittelbach: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)
To answer your question we must collect some facts:

1. Floating environments doesn't allow any page breaks.
2. `longtable` or `supertabular` aren't floating environments and can't be used inside them.
3. Only the package `tabularx` and `ltxtable` (combination of `longtable` and `tabularx`) can handel a given width.
4. You can't simple interrupt the `twocolumn` mode.
5. When a document is set in `twocolumn`, yet you can switch inside the document between `onecolumn` and `twocolumn`

Based of this fact and your request I suggest a combination of the package `multicol` and `ltxtable`

The package `multicol` provided the environment `multicols`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable,ltxtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{count}
\setcounter{count}{1}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myltxtable.tex}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{3.5}
\begin{longtable}{X}
\caption{caption}\\\endfirsthead
\toprule
foo\\bar\\foo\\bar\\
foo\\bar\\foo\\bar\\
foo\\bar\\foo\\bar\\
foo\\bar\\foo\\bar\\
foo\\bar\\foo\\bar\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\onecolumn
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{begin multicols}]
\lipsum\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{myltxtable.tex}
\twocolumn
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

**ORIG**

I hope I understand you correct. Some time ago I wrote a small post about the package `supertabular` on the [FAQ Dante](http://projekte.dante.de/DanteFAQ/Supertabular) (in German) which is able to handle two column.

One important fact is that `supertabular` calculates the width of the rows `c`, `l` and `r` on every new page again.

Here a small example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{forloop,supertabular}
\newcounter{count}
\setcounter{count}{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead{erster Tabellenkopf\\}
\tablehead{Tabellenkopf\\}
\tabletail{Fortsetzung n\"achste Seite\\}
\tablelasttail{letze Seite\\}
\tablecaption{supertabular-Tabelle}
\begin{supertabular}{c}
\whiledo{\value{count} < 100}{\stepcounter{count}
   \arabic{count} \\}
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again!  Please see my comment above asking how to make the float single column.

Comment: @AlexT.: I edited my post.

Comment: This post saved my life. Even though the workarounds with supertabular may be helpful, it was much easier to switch to onecolumn mode locally!